# css - not able to vertical center span with font-style "Luckiest Guy"

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I find that I am not able to vertical center span with font-style "**Luckiest Guy**".
[image]

I tried to apply `display: flex;align-items: center;` on the `span` but not working.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span>Luckiest Guy Font</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luckiest+Guy&display=swap");

#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 60px;
  span {
    font-family: "Luckiest Guy", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-browser-lh9f8?file=/src/App.vue:441-453

Comment: ... well, set `justify-content: center;` to the span ...

Comment: @Vovan_Super I want vertical align

Comment: which browser are you using

Comment: Looks pretty centered to me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: No issue with Chrome (95.0.4638.54) and Edge (95.0.1020.40)

Comment: If you want "vertical align" then span is display: block; If you use display: flex; then  justify-content: center;

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 10 using Chrome, Edge, Firefox. What OS are you using?

Comment: @ĐỗvănThắng justify-content: center does horizontal alignment. The code in the question correctly uses align-items: center for vertical alignment.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have problem and it works fine. Maybe you have some other classes that affect on this tag.

Also you can set vertical-align:baseline; in span tag styles.

```css
.span-style{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
border:1px solid black;
height:40px;
vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="span-style">
Hello world
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It works on other `font-style` but not working on `"Luckiest Guy"`

Comment: have you tried !important keyword?